# How to know the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$?

Tags: calculus

> Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be a series of positive terms. Show that if
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log \left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \right) = g > 1$$
> then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent.

Consider $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| =L<1$ convergence:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|& =\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\log\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|}  \\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|} \\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|}{1/n}} \\
&=e^{-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right)}{1/n}} \\
&=e^{-\frac\theta n} \\
&\approx e^{0} \\
&=1
\end{align*}
and I don't know how to next step.

Comment: You have a number of recent questions, and they generally look like homework questions. Can you let us know what you are working on and why so that we may best help point you in the right direction?

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your proof is not correct.

Comment: how to proof is right

Comment: @dream Assuming $g$ finite the given condition implies that the ratio $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\to 1^+$, form here we can proceed for a proof.

Comment: This is almost unreadable on a smartphone. Put that long sentence out of aligned environment and use $\exp(\cdot)$ function instead of $e^\cdot$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that for $g\in \left(1,\infty\right)$

$$n \log \left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \right) \to g  \implies \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\to 1^+$$

then

$$n \log \left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \right)=n \left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -1\right)\frac{\log \left( 1+\left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -1\right) \right)}{\left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -1\right)}\to g$$

which implies

$$n \left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -1\right)\to g$$

and for [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe%27s_test) the series converges.

To complete the proof we need to consider the case with $g=\infty$.